# Are we able to print out the address for string literal?

Tags: c

I did a google on that, and I realized that some say it can
some say it cannot.

I would just like to verify.

For example

```
 char gchararr1i[] = "testing 123"; // global char array init
 char *gptr1i = "hello", *gptr2ui; // global char pointer init and un-init
 float gfloati = 123.4; // global float var init
 double gdoubleui; // global double var un-int


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   printf("\n Address of  string literals \"testing 123\" = %p and \"hello\" = %p \n", gchararr1i, gptr1i);// output the addresses of string literals "testing 123" and "hello" 

   f1(10, -20, 30.3, 'A', 45.67);
   exit(0);               
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that, although technically you should cast the pointers to `void *`.

Comment: what do you mean just cast the pointers to void *? anyway, if it's possible, the way I printed is it correct?

Comment: E.g. `printf( "address=%p\n", (void *)gchararr1i );` The C specification says that the argument for `%p` *must* be a `void *`, although in most cases it makes no difference.

Comment: Did this code gave correct output ?

Comment: Technically you're not getting the address of a string literal. You're getting the address of the object you initialized with a string literal. Something like `#define gchararr1i "testing 123"` and printing `(void *)gchararr1i` with the `%p` format specification would give you a pointer to the string data.

Comment: Please learn how to eliminate the inessential from your questions — see how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  The `float` and `double` variables are unused, as are the arguments to `main()`, and the function call to `f1()` is not germane either.  I'd use `return(0)` instead of `exit(0)` which saves on a header — you'd only need `<stdio.h>` then. However, it isn't a major problem as there isn't much code, but it would make it clearer what you're asking about.

Answer (score 7):

You can take the address of a string literal, but you can't be certain that two string literals with the exact same contents will be at the same address (or that they won't have the same address). The compiler toolchain is free to do as it wishes in that regard.

The standard even permits one string literal to share memory with another.  For example the address of `"world"` might 'point into' the literal `"hello world"`.  I'm not aware of an implementation that does this, but I haven't checked for it either.

Answer (score 5):

> Are we able to print out the address for string literal?

Yes.  A simple example to print out the address for a string literal.

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) "Hello Word!");
```

Output

```
0x100403055
```

---

The following prints out the address of the first element of `gchararr1i[]`.  This may or may not be the address of the string literal.  The string literal may not even exist separately in code.

```
char gchararr1i[] = "testing 123";
printf("%p\n", (void *) gchararr1i);
```

Output

```
0x22caa0
```

The following prints out the address value of the pointer `gptr1i` which happens to be the address of the string literal `"hello"`.

```
char *gptr1i = "hello";
printf("%p\n", (void *) gptr1i);
```

Output

```
0x100403060
```

--

Detail: `"%p` is only defined with printing `void*` pointers.  When printing object pointers other than `void*`, cast to `void *` first.  [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368780/are-we-able-to-print-out-the-address-for-string-literal/36369040#comment60356697_36368780). Note: to print function pointers see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36363566/2410359).

```
int x;
// printf("%p\n", x);
printf("%p\n", (void *)&x);
```

Comment: I always thoughts that %p is used to print out the address of the pointer. No?

Comment: `"%p"` is only for printing `void*` pointers.  All pointers, except pointers to functions, readily convert to `void*`.  So casting a pointer to `void *` is the robust code approach.  _Many_ implementations will give the same result if the cast is omitted, but that is not robust code and _technically_ is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why *"technically"* UB? There's nothing unclear about it.

Comment: @Ilja for learners UB is often a deep, foreign concept. The the idea of "it works on my machine" is proof of valid behavior. Yes, printing a non-`void *` with `"%p"` is UB, but often performs as desired on many platforms. Hence the _technically_, even if it "works " on one's machine, it is is not abiding by the C standard.